# Changing twice "for" loop for single "for" loop (SORTING)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

This is my first post here. I have to sort values that returns True or False. My problem is that, it take too long in two loops but I can't change it to single loop.

Here is code for the sorting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (f(arr[i]) == true) {
       for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
           if(f(arr[j]) == false){
               swap(arr[i],arr[j]);
           }
       }    
}
```

And here is function:

```
bool isEven(int e) { return e%2 == 0; }
```

True vaules must be first in array and false vals on the right side(place that left). I must get rid of that inside loop. Thanks for help and advices. I can't make any new arrays, that must be done with the one in loop (arr[]).

For example for array: 1,2,3,4,5,6 -> 2 4 6 1 5 3.

Comment: The algorithm you are looking for is `std::partition()`. It works with two positions: one moving from front to back and the other from back to front until they meet. You'd find the next position with an element in the wrong location on both ends and swap them. If you want to look at it that way it use three loops (one outer and two inner ones) but it is fast.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in that inner loop you start at 0 even though you know that all elements in [0, i] are false. So I think you can do this:

```
int i = 0;
int j = size - 1;
while (i < j) {
   if (f(arr[i] == true) {
       while (f[arr[j] == true && j > i) {
           j -= 1;
       }
       swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
   }
   i += 1;
}
```

Note that while the above looks like it has 2 loops each element is examined only once so the runtime is O(n) as opposed to your original solution which is O(n^2).

Comment: Actually, the above is buggy. I think what you want is more or less what std:partition does. Updated the code to show that instead (as it actually works).